# What is expressed through もし...たら here

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Full context:

> 友達申請をしてくださって、ありがとうございます。
>
> アンドレアスさん、でいいですか？もし呼び方が違っていたら教えてください。
>   「みんなの日本語」を最後までやり終えたのですね。すばらしいです。
>
> 私は英語の勉強も、もちろんしていますが、日本語を教える勉強も始めたので、力になれたらうれしいです。
>
> 何でも聞いてください。一緒に頑張りましょう。

Sentence in question:

> もし呼び方が違っていたら教えてください。

My attempt at translation:

> "Please think whether the pronunciation is off or not."

I've encountered (もし)...たら constructions in several cases:

1) Where it expresses the prototypical conditional:
"When I do X, Y will happen (eventually)".
今食べ過ぎたら、多分眠られません。

2) Where it expresses a thing which hasn't happened in reality:
"If X had been the case, I wouldn't have done Y"
喪主昨日雨が降っていたら、買い物には出かけなかっただろう。

3) in certain set phrases like:
...Vたらいいですか。...Vたらどう?

4) When it expresses that X happened in consequence of Y:
薬を飲んだら、元気になりました。

However, in the sentence in question, at least as far as I understand it, it expresses the translated "whether...or..." construction.
Since 考える　is used in part 2, it's pretty difficult to coax a basic "When X, then Y" interpretation into it. Basically, this is what separates it from all the other cases I've described above. Whenever I encountered たら, it was somehow possible to translate it into a very literal if-clause without turning it into absolute gibberish. This isn't possible here anymore:

> "When the pronunciation is off, please think."

This is also the reason why I'm asking about it here.
I don't trust my own translation, even though it would make perfect sense in this context ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should review the basic meaning of the words.

- 呼ぶ is "to call", not "to pronounce". 呼び方 refers to how to call you.
- 教えてください is "please tell/teach me", rather than "please think". Are you mixing 考える with 教える?
- もし～たら is simply "if ～ then".

The letter is asking if it's okay to call you アンドレアスさん (among other options such as a nickname or a family name).

> もし呼び方が違っていたら教えてください。
>   Please tell me if my way of calling you is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I mixed up 考える and 教える, I'm sry ^^

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a simple misreading. 教える is not "to think," it's "to teach/tell/inform".

> If "Andreas" is incorrect, please let me know.

You can think of 違う as "to differ" if you prefer.